# How do I include the sat4j library in eclipse java IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, libraries, sat4j

I've tried so many times to import the sat4j library (https://www.sat4j.org/index.php) into the java IDE eclipse by adding the jar files in the lib folder which came with the download of sat4j library (`commons-beanutils.jar`, `commons-cli.jar`, `commons-logging.jar`...).
But somehow I always get the error message Invalid ZIP file for every jar file I tried to include and now I'm wondering if its even possible to include it in eclipse at all..

Comment: maybe helpful to know which file and how you are trying to add where - usually `*.jar` files are added to a project in Eclipse... and yes, it is possible to add `sat4j-sat.jar` to an Eclipse project and use it

Comment: I tried to add the files in the lib folder which came with the download of sat4j library (commons-beanutils.jar, commons-cli.jar, commons-logging.jar...). But I didn't know there was a sat4j-sat.jar file

Comment: I believe you must download from the 'Precompiled binaries for manual inclusion in Java projects' - seems like you got the source code and the content of `lib` are the libraries used by SAT4J itself

Comment: aah now I see, yes you are totally right I downloaded the source code. I really didn't know , thank you very much!!

Comment: I found the right jar file and including it worked perfectly now! Thank you! @user16320675 :)

Comment: that's a good idea, I will edit my question